# CSV string to array when there is \n in body

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, csv, object

I'm trying to convert a CSV string into an array of array of objects. Although the issue is, there is a bunch of `\n` in the body from the incoming request, with are causing the request to split and mess up all the code. I'm attempting to fix this even with `\n` in the body
The string looks like this, all the messages that are strings from the incoming request, starts with a `\"` and finishes with `\"`.

```
"id,urn,title,body,risk,s.0.id,s.1.id,s.2.id,a.0.id,a.1.id,a.2.id,a.3.id
302,25,\"Secure Data\",\"Banking can save a lot of time but it’s not without risks. Scammers treat your bank account as a golden target –
it can be a quick and untraceable way to get money from you\n\n**TOP TIPS**\n\n**Always read your banks rules.** These tips don’t replace your banks rules - \
in fact we fully support them. If you don’t follow their rules, you may not get your money back if you are defrauded \n\n**Saving passwords or allowing auto-complete.** 
Saving passwords in your browser is great for remembering them but if a hacker is able to access your computer, they will also have access to your passwords. 
When on your banking site the password box we recommend you don’t enable the auto-complete function – a hacked device means they are able to gain access using this method \n\n**Use a 
PIN number on your device.** It’s really important to lock your device when you’re not using it.\",,2,20,52,1,2,3,4"
```

I have attempted to make it smaller since there is a bunch of content, but the string that comes is basically the above, The big string with is messing my code up start at `Banking can save` and finishes at `not using it.` I have several other datas that have the same type of body, and always comes inside `\" body \"`, I have been attempting to perform a function to separate the content from this CSV string, into an array of array or an array of objects.

This is what I attempted:

```
function csv_To_Array(str, delimiter = ",") {
      const header_cols = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter);
      const row_data = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n");
      const arr = row_data.map(function (row) {
        const values = row.split(delimiter);
        const el = header_cols.reduce(function (object, header, index) {
          object[header] = values[index];
          return object;
        }, {});
        return el;
      });

      // return the array
      return arr;
    }
```

I have thought on using regex too, where I would split if it had a comma of a \n, although if there is a /" it will split when it finds the next /":

```
array.split(/,/\n(?!\d)/))
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunatly, it splitted wrong

Comment: Hm.  [Seems to work fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0bfp643a/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
    csvData.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
```

Once you've used that to replace the new lines, or removed them, this code will help you get started with understanding how to build an array from the new CSV string:

```js
  const splitTheArrayAndLogIt = () => {
    const everySingleCharacter = csvData.split(""); // <-- this is a new array 
    console.log(everySingleCharacter);

    const splitAtCommas = csvData.split(",");
    console.log(splitAtCommas);
  }
```

Comment: This helped a lot, although I would need an array from the data. For example, and if I split it by ',' it will split the body in half

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if that gets you any closer?

Comment: It almost worked, I got an issue because it didn't get the newline from end of `.3.id` and then it joined, `a.3.id306`